# Как искать конкретную анкету по определенным критериям?

Tags: java

Я хочу создать хранилище, которое будет держать в себе данные о людях, будет создавать индивидуальный файл (txt) в определенной директории и хранить там данные.

Затем я хочу искать конкретную анкету по ID и сортировать по заданным параметра анкеты, пример - найти всех сереж в хранилище или найти одного конкретного по ID

Я не могу понять как лучше хранить, и получать эти данные, первая мысль везде, кроме id получать строку

План

1. Получаю данные от пользователя
   0) ID
   1) Фамилия
   2) Имя
   3) Отчество
   4) Дата рождения
   5) Страна
   6) Город
   7) Пол
   8) маил
   9) контактный телефон
   10) Место работы

   1.1 Проверяю данные и если все верно, то перехожу к пункту 2 а если нет то говорю о некоректном вводе и прошу повторить снова
2. Создаю на основе данных анкету конкретного человека
3. Заношу Анкету в Хранилище
4. Спрашиваю хочет ли пользователь занести еще анкеты, если да, то повторяю пункт 1 а если нет, то закрываю программу!

Comment: а по хеш-коду не пробовали? старый-добрый способ))

Comment: Каким способом вы хотите осуществить ваш план?